# How to enable emoji support in Wine?

Tags: linux, windows, fonts, wine, winapi

I've made a simple program that displays a UTF-16 character (a cat emoji) inside a MessageBox. While it's working on a Windows 10 VM it displays two blank boxes under Wine. How can I fix this?

[Windows 10 on the left, Wine on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXh4E.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably will not work. Wine is a simple tool just to run Apps.

You should make a Windows Virtual Machine (VMware (Linux and Windows hosts), Hyper-V (Windows Host), Virtual Box (Linux and Windows Hosts)) to support your emoji programs.

That will work.

Comment: I already have a Windows VM but I'd prefer not to use it. Wine can run MS Office, Photoshop and a lot of AAA games. Those are very complex programs. Does it *really* have that much of a problem with emojis?

Comment: Complex Apps don’t usually run on Wine because it is such a simple emulator.  That is why I suggest a Windows machine